# PHP accessing a variable from another function

Tags: php, function

So, I have two php functions:

```
function RADD_FILE_GLOBAL(){
   ...
   $file_att = implode(",",$files); 
}
```

I need to access this `$file_att` variable from another function:

```
function FILE_NAME(){
 // need $file_att here
}
```

How do I access a variable from another function?

Comment: you can define this variable as global

Comment: You could pass it in as a parameter

Comment: @Dezza, for passing this parameter inside function, you need to call second function inside first function. so why don't you declare it as global?

Comment: @MahaDev global var is not a good practice, of course it has its benefits, but not in this case.

Comment: use class/oop concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set a return value from the first function which could either be passed as a parameter to the second function or declared, within the second function, as a global.

```
function RADD_FILE_GLOBAL(){
    /* other code */
   $file_att = implode(",",$files);
   return $file_att; 
}
function FILE_NAME( $file_att ){
    /* do something with variable */
}
/* or */
function FILE_NAME(){
    global $file_att;
    /* do something with var */
}

/* run first function, return a value */
$file_att=call_user_func( 'RADD_FILE_GLOBAL' );

/* later */
call_user_func( 'FILE_NAME',$file_att );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$file_att = '';

function RADD_FILE_GLOBAL(){
   global $file_att;
   ...
   $file_att = implode(",",$files); 
}

function FILE_NAME(){
    global $file_att;
 // you have now $file_att here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use global but it's a bit ugly and totally useless. The best way is what @Dezza says, pass it as a parameter :

```
function RADD_FILE_GLOBAL(){
   $file_att = implode(",",$files); 
   $file_name = FILE_NAME($file_att);
}

function FILE_NAME($file_att){
    // use $file_att
}
```

Comment: Then call it from another function ? or from somewhere else ? You have to call the function at one moment...

Comment: But this updated variable will not be available outside of this function if you call from somewhere else.

Comment: Well the original question was how to use a variable from another function not how to store a result globally.